# What are the verse in the Vedas and upanishades that support dualistic philosophy of dvaita vedanta?

Tags: vedas, upanishads, dvaita

Dvaita Vedanta is dualistic school of philosophy and interpretation of the Vedas and upanishades.
Dvaita Vedanta is a dualistic interpretation of the Vedas which espouses dualism by theorizing the existence of two separate realities. ... Madhvacharya posits God as being personal and saguna, that is endowed with attributes and qualities (in human terms, which are not believed to be able to fully describe God).

So what are the verse that support this dualistic philosophy?

And also that the word is real and not illusions as oppose to advaita vedanta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the verse in the Vedas and upanishades that support dualistic philosophy of dvaita vedanta?

The most interesting thing is how Madhvacharya interprets the following verse from the Chandogya Upanishad:

> 6.8.7 - स आत्मातत्त्वमसि
>
> sa AtmAtattvamasi

Depending on how you split the word, it can be:

> sa AtmA **tat** tvam asi (You are that self)

Or

> sa AtmA **atat** tvam asi (You are **not** that self)

Both are valid according to Sanskrit grammar, but since Madhvacharya thinks the message of the Upanishads is Dvaita, he will interpret Dvaitism wherever he can.

In reality interpreting this verse in this way doesn't make sense from the context this verse is in, but that's another issue.

So to answer your question, this verse is used to support Dvaita.

Other less ambiguous verses supporting Dvaita from the Upanishads are as follows:

> Mandukya Upanishad 3.1.1 - **Two birds**, inseparable companions, perch on the same tree,
> one eats the fruit, the other looks on. The first bird is our
> individual self feeding on the pleasures and pains of this world;
> The other is the universal Self, silently witnessing all.

> [Kaushitaki Upanishad](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe01/sbe01241.htm)  - For **Brahman makes him**, the individual soul, whom he wishes to lead up from these worlds, do a good deed; and he makes him, whom he wishes to lead down from these worlds, do a bad deed.

> [Kaushitaki Upanishad](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe01/sbe01241.htm)  - He is the guardian of the world, he is the king of the world, he is the lord of the universe, and he is **my (Indra's) self**.

These are just some of the verses. There are more. Also, there are more Dvaita verses than Advaita verses in the Upanishads.

Comment: Atat vamasi  is right fitting into the context because you net picking one statement and state that its out context is unfair, because whole point of madhvas and his followers argument is about context. This statement comes when sveta keta univesity gold medalist disrespects his father uddalakka on arriving back to his home.  That is where this whole story come about.. Uddalakka never have said anything to boost ego of his son who is already disrespecting his father..Suppose he is saysing that his son is God as per yours and advaitic acharyas commentry will his ego bolster up or down???

Comment: whole of scriptures is unnecessary for world that is illusion acccording to advaita..  i would take  that whole scriptures are only giving for real and dualistic world.